# My total = total + b (while in for e in b: ) wont add them together?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from typing import List

b: List[int] = [52, 58, 15, 83]
total = 0

for e in b:
    total = total + b
print(total)
```

New learner here, but it seems like my piece of code just doesn't seem to work, its also to be noted i tired everything by looking at errors checking and grammar mistakes, ect. It would be great if someone would just give me a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes it does, Thanks for asking Packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding b to the total, but b is the list. you should be adding an element from the list, which is, in your code, e.

So, it should be `total = total + e`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have here is you cannot use the operand `+` between `int` and `list`.

What you're likely seeing is a `TypeError` that would indicate this.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

If you reversed your `+` to `b + total` it would return a different `TypeError`

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

---

In your loop, you're not using the variable you define in your loop to access the elements in the list: `e`. This would allow you to utilize `+` as `total` and `e` are both integers.

```
for e in b:
    total = total + e

    #208
```

You can also use `sum()` to calculate the total value of a list without using a loop.

```
sum(b)
#208
```